# Hide input if mouse not moved for 5 seconds

Tags: html

I have a HTML img input for the page reqad.co.nf as a full screen function, how would I make this input hide if the mouse isn't moved for 5 seconds, and reappear if it moves again?`<input type="image" src="fullscreenico.png" align="right" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">`

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't specified JavaScript as a possible solution?

Comment: No, you can use JavaScript, it just needs to be compatible with an image input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet with a JQuery solution:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       var lastTimeMouseMoved;
       var alreadyPrompt = false;
       $(document).mousemove(function(e){
           lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
           alreadyPrompt = false;
           $(".theInputIdLikeToHide").show();
       }); 
       setInterval(function(){
         if(!alreadyPrompt){
         var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            if (currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved > 5000) {
                $(".theInputIdLikeToHide").hide();
                alreadyPrompt = true;
            }
          }
       }, 500);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="theInputIdLikeToHide">
```